# Opt out of the new Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

How do I Opt out of the new Google Maps?
There is no help and feedback button in the top right corner. 
Fortunately Mapquest and Yahoo Maps still work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this URI for now: https://www.google.ca/maps?output=classic&dg=opt

Answer (score 0):

See if the "?" or "Help" button is in the BOTTOM right of the new Google Maps page. It took me two tries, but was able to default to the old Google Maps.

Comment: Can you put a brief summary of the steps you took in your answer?  That way it will be helpful to people reading it later.

Comment: This is where I got the steps: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3045828?hl=en